# How to check for a key/node existence in JSON c#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My Json looks like below.
I want to check if the following key/nodes exist or not in the below Json.

> 1st node-> AutomationFramework.Technique.Available
>
> 2nd node->Verify.Customer

```
    {
      "$type": "Config",
      "Available": true,
      "Verify": {
        "$type": "UserList`2"
        "Customer":"Peter"
      },
      "Identification": true,
      "Verification": false,
      "AutomationFramework": [
        {
          "$type": "custom",
          "Name": "ATL",
          "Technique": {
            "$type": "Technique",
            "PropertyName": "Name",
            "Available": true
          },
          "SolveTechnique": {
            "$type": "Userdefined",
            "Available": true
          },
          "AITechnique": {
            "$type": "AI",
            "X_Value": 2,
            "Y_Value": 3,
            "Available": true
          },
          "WaitTechnique": {
            "$type": "Recurssion",
            "Available": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I tried with the following code (`ParseJson` below is a method to parse JSON which I have created):

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(ParseJson(@"C:\Test\Test.Config"));
IEnumerable<JToken> token = obj.SelectTokens("AutomationFramework.Technique.Available", errorWhenNoMatch: false);
```

Here it is returning null even if the node is present.

I want a generic method that could handle all scenarios. Any help will be appreciated.

The method should return `True`/`False` based on the existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working because `AutomationFramework` is a list, not an object.

Also, be sure to cast the result to an appropriate type. If you know the type of the token, you can cast directly in place. If you don't know the type at compile time, you can store in a `JToken` variable instead.

In your code you are using `SelectTokens`. But if you are expecting only one of that token, you should use `SelectToken` instead.

Assuming that the desired node `Technique` will always be present in the first item of the `AutomationFramework` list, you could do:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(ParseJson(@"C:\Test\Test.Config"));
bool avail = (bool)obj.SelectToken("AutomationFramework[0].Technique.Available", errorWhenNoMatch: false);
string cust = (string)obj.SelectToken("Verify.Customer", errorWhenNoMatch: false);
```

Comment: I upvoted you, but we should also notice that the docs about SelectTokens (note the final "s") seems wrong. It states that should return an enumeration of found elements, not null. By the way, I personally find nonsense returning null when the signature returns an IEnumerable.

Comment: Returning null should be explicitly declared in any API interface. Good thing that c#8 introduces nullable reference types, people should adopt that.